# Add a character to the next n nonempty lines after regex in bash

Tags: sed, grep

I have a configuration file that contains the following lines and want to know of a way to add a ';' at the beginning of each line following [treadmill] until the next blank line. I would like to do this from a script since these lines are to be included depending on the configuration of that environment.

```
[treadmill]
type = aor
contact = server.domain.com

[A_SRV]
type = aor
contact = serverA.domain.com

[B_SRV]
type = aor
contact = serverB.domain.com

[treadmill]
type = identify
endpoint = treadmill
match = server.domain.com

[C_SRV_IDEN]
type = identify
endpoint = sip
match = server.domain.com

[treadmill]
type = endpoint
context = LocalSets
dtmf_mode = rfc4733
disallow = all
allow = ulaw
direct_media = no
aors = treadmill
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `sed '/\[treadmill\]/,/^$/{//!s/.*/;&/}'`

Comment: @stevesliva.  Probably slightly better to use `s/^/;/` to do the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

`sed -e '/\[treadmill\]/,/^$/{//!s/^/;/}' treadmill.txt`

Explanation:

- `/\[treadmill\]/,/^$/` uses `/START/,/END/` syntax to apply the subsequent commands in curly braces `{}` in the START to END range of lines, inclusive of the START and END lines.  `/^$/` requires an entirely empty line, no whitespace.
- `{//!s/^/;/}` is one command in braces, applied within the above range.
- `//!` means, "didn't match the previous match," as `//` is the previous match.  This prevents the START and END lines from being processed
- `//!s/^/;/` chains the replacement `s/^/;/` onto lines where `//!` is true.  That adds a semicolon to each line between START and END
- My initial suggestion for the semicolon addition was `s/.*/;&/` - this replaces `.*` with `;&` where `&` in the replacement side corresponds to whatever `.*` matched. As @WilliamPursell commented, this is potentially less clear than `s/^/;/`
- In some shells, the `!` is a special character that needs backslash escaping as well.  It should be okay unescaped in bash.

**Output:**

```
[treadmill]
;type = aor
;contact = server.domain.com

[A_SRV]
type = aor
contact = serverA.domain.com

[B_SRV]
type = aor
contact = serverB.domain.com

[treadmill]
;type = identify
;endpoint = treadmill
;match = server.domain.com

[C_SRV_IDEN]
type = identify
endpoint = sip
match = server.domain.com

[treadmill]
;type = endpoint
;context = LocalSets
;dtmf_mode = rfc4733
;disallow = all
;allow = ulaw
;direct_media = no
;aors = treadmill
```

Comment: Nicely done. To complement the info re `!` being special: that normally applies only to interactive shells (with history expansion turned on). AFAIK, using `!` inside `'…'` (single-quoted strings) is safe in POSIX-like shells, however (`csh` is a different story).

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk '!NF { f = 0 }
         { print (f == 1 ? ";" : "") $0 }
     $0 ~ /^\[treadmill\]$/
         { f = 1 }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty convoluted however it does work.

```
grep -ne "^\[treadmill\]" $DIRPATH/pjsip.conf.sample | cut -d : -f 1 | awk '{print $1" on"}' > lines.txt
grep -n '^$' $DIRPATH/pjsip.conf.sample | cut -d : -f 1 | awk '{print $1" off"}' >> lines.txt
cat lines.txt | sort -n > lines2.txt

IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator

declare -i arr4
items=0

for i in $(cat lines2.txt) ; do
    SWITCH=`echo $i | cut -d' ' -f 2`
    LINE=`echo $i | cut -d' ' -f 1`
    if [ "$SWITCH" = "on" ] && [ $SWITCHED -eq 0 ]; then
        SWITCHED=1
        arr4[$items]=$LINE
        ((++items))
    fi
    if [ "$SWITCH" = "off" ] && [ $SWITCHED -eq 1 ]; then
        SWITCHED=0
        arr4[$items]=$LINE
        ((++items))
    fi

done

count=${#arr4[@]}

let SECTIONS=$count/2
let SECTIONS-=1

for i in `seq 0 $SECTIONS` ; do
    let START=$((arr4[$i*2]))
    let END=$((arr4[($i*2)+1]))-1
    for j in `seq ${START} ${END}` ; do
        sed -i "$j s/^/;/" $DIRPATH/pjsip.conf.sample
    done
done

rm lines.txt lines2.txt
```